# How to map <BS> to do nothing?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, alacritty

(I'm using Alacritty + NeoVim, I'm not sure about whether this issue is from Alacritty or NeoVim.)

I want to map `<BS>` in insert mode to do nothing, i.e. `<Nop>`. I have tried:

```
inoremap <BS> <Nop>
noremap! <BS> <Nop>
```

I have checked that by typing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> then press <kbd>⌫</kbd>, the output is exactly `<BS>` in insert mode.

But the backspace indeed disabled in the mode when I press <kbd>:</kbd>. So how to do the same for insert mode?

Comment: The `inoremap <BS> <Nop>` command worked both in Vim and NeoVim for me.

Comment: Use this command:  
  `verbose imap <BS>`  
to report what, if anything, <BS> is mapped to.

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff: Sir you are awesome, I read that line in the file that is exactly what cause this behaviour.

Comment: Is it possible to detect the current input-method chosen in (Neo)Vim? I only want to stop `<BS>` when certain input-method is chosen. I need the auto-pairs plugin, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have solved this myself with the help of comments by @Chris Heithoff I'm going to answer it myself. As comment stated: when some mapping *should* work but it didn't, thne the reason is probably because some plugins also doing the mapping for the same key. To check it:

```
:verbose imap YOUR_KEY
```

where `YOUR_KEY` is optional, if omitted then all will be listed. And I found this is useful since I want to read them in a larger window.

---

If you're interested about the intent of `<BS>` to `<Nop>` mapping:

In short:

- Alacritty doesn't support *inline* editing when typing Chinese in insert mode.

  - For example, there are 3 components `ㄋㄧˇ` to form the word `妳`, **Both** these components **and** the result `妳` will not be shown in insert mode before I hit `Enter` after typing them all.
- Even worse, if I want to delete some component before I hit the `Enter`, it will delete not only the last component **BUT ALSO** the word already entered before `妳`. (I hate it!)

So what I wanted to do is a shortcut to **toggle** `<BS>` when entering insert mode. Here is the result :)

```
" Chinese Input.
inoremap <Up> <Nop>
inoremap <Down> <Nop>
inoremap <Left> <Nop>
inoremap <Right> <Nop>
inoremap <nowait> <C-C> <Esc>:call <SID>toggleLockOnBS()<CR>a
inoremap <nowait> <Esc> <Esc>:call <SID>removeBSLock()<CR>
let s:lockOnBS=0
function! s:toggleLockOnBS() abort
    if s:lockOnBS
        call s:removeBSLock()
    else
        call s:putBSLock()
    endif
endfunction
function! s:removeBSLock() abort
    execute 'inoremap <buffer><silent> <BS> <C-R>=AutoPairsDelete()<CR>'
    echo '<BS> enabled for 中文.'
    let s:lockOnBS = 0
endfunction
function! s:putBSLock() abort
    execute 'inoremap <buffer><silent> <BS> <Nop>'
    echo '<BS> disabled for 中文.'
    let s:lockOnBS = 1
endfunction
```

the line `inoremap <buffer><silent> <BS> <C-R>=AutoPairsDelete()<CR>` is to restore the mapping of some plugin which also want to map `<BS>` to something else. Feel free to change it to whatever you like.